# Adding media when javascript button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have created a JS button that generates random facts when clicked.
now i want each String(fact) to have media below to make the fact more interesting and fun.

```
<script> <!-- arrays -->function GetValue(){ var myarray= new Array()
myarray[0]="your lungs are worth $58,200 each,heart will fetch $57,000, and your kidneys are good for another $91,400,your DNA will fetch more than 9M$,while your bone marrow, your most valuable possession, is worth $23 million all by itself. Therefore your body market value is exactly: $45,618,575.82." 
myarray[1]="Hans Langseth the man with the world's longest beard 5.33 m (17 ft 6 in)tripped on his long beard. He lost his balance and fell, breaking his neck from the unexpected accident! He died instantaneously."
myarray[2]="A Sesame Street episode (ep. 847) was aired on TV in 1976,it was so scary that the authorities had to pull it off due to several complaints from parents saying their children screamed in horror."<!--END-var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];//alert(random); document.getElementById("fact button").innerHTML=random;}</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input  type="button" id="fact_button" value="Fact Button" onclick="GetValue();" />
```

Comment: What media are you talking about? I'm not sure if understand the question. Are you missing some code?

Comment: Yurgh, `<!-- arrays -->` is straight away a syntax error. These are HTML comments, not Javascript comments. Open your console, it's yelling "Syntax error".

Comment: @JeremyThille, those comments work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rb3hy8cm/

Comment: Are you telling me HTML comments work in Javascript?? What the f...

Comment: Yes apparently you can. I wasn't aware of that either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to show media like images, for instance, this is one way to do it:

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const factsArr = [
      {
        image: 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
        content: "your lungs are worth $58,200 each,heart will fetch $57,000, and your kidneys are good for another $91,400,your DNA will fetch more than 9M$,while your bone marrow, your most valuable possession, is worth $23 million all by itself. Therefore your body market value is exactly: $45,618,575.82."
      },
      {
        image: 'http://via.placeholder.com/200x140',
        content: "Hans Langseth the man with the world's longest beard 5.33 m (17 ft 6 in)tripped on his long beard. He lost his balance and fell, breaking his neck from the unexpected accident! He died instantaneously."
      },
      {
        image: 'http://via.placeholder.com/200x100',
        content: "A Sesame Street episode (ep. 847) was aired on TV in 1976,it was so scary that the authorities had to pull it off due to several complaints from parents saying their children screamed in horror."
      }
    ];
  
    
    document.getElementById('generate-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
      const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * factsArr.length);
      document.getElementById('random-fact-content').innerHTML = factsArr[idx].content;
      document.getElementById('random-fact-image').setAttribute('src', factsArr[idx].image)
    })
      
}
```

```html
<button id="generate-btn">Generate Random Fact</button>
<div id="random-fact-content"></div>
<img id="random-fact-image"></img>
```